# TortoiseHg and hg purge: do they work together?

Tags: mercurial, tortoise-hg

TortoiseHg has settings to enable the Mercurial Purge extension. But does it actually have a drop down menu or something so that you can purge a directory without having to go to the command line? Or is that extension setting just a convenient way to editing extension settings without needing to load a text file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From top menu bar in TortoiseHg Workbench simply select: **Repository -> Purge**. 
It will perform purge even without the need to install the Purge extension.

Comment: Is there a way to purge a specific directory? That menu only works on a per-repo basis.

Comment: AFAIK, no. Extension also works on repo-wide basis only

Comment: It works on sub-directories too. Just do `hg purge ./`.

Comment: OK, you meant main menu in TortoiseHg Workbench. There is no Purge action in explorer context menu itself.